# Why isn't the word "white" capitalized when referring to the race?

Tags: capitalization, proper-nouns, biology

I was surprised to find that there's a growing convention of capitalizing the word "black" when referring to the race, i.e.:

> A Black person.

I thought this was wrong, because I thought it was only proper nouns, like cultures, nationalities and ethnicities, that were to be capitalized. *Black* denotes a race, and nothing more, as there are many nationalities, cultures and ethnicities that fall within the black race. Calling *black* a culture or ethnicity would be reductive.

However, this capitalization rule apparently applies to race as well; see the 10th item [here](https://webapps.towson.edu/ows/capitalization_rules.htm).

If this rule is in fact true, then that means *black* is to be capitalized when denoting a person of the black race. It also means that *white* is to be capitalized when denoting a person of the white race. Caucasian, which is a word denoting a race, is capitalized. It is a synonym to *white*.

So, if *Caucasian* is capitalized, and if people want *black* to be capitalized when referring to race, why isn't *white* supposed to be capitalized? Is *white* not a race? I'm no biologist, nor anthropologist, but if *white* is too genetically broad to be considered a race, then I'm pretty sure *black* would be too.

**EDIT:** As user Cascabel pointed out in the comments, *Caucasian* is derived from the Caucasus Mountains, which is a place, and therefore a proper noun. Therefore, regardless of what capitalization rules one employs, *Caucasian* has to be capitalized, and is therefore not necessarily an example of people capitalizing racial classification.

**EDIT 2:**

CMS have changed their preferred capitalization rules as of the 17th edition, which means that the answers to the linked [post](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/173974/are-white-and-black-ever-capitalized-when-referring-to-people) that this post was designated a duplicate of, are no longer valid.

Comment: You appear to refer to a recent trend which sees the term Black capitalized when referring to people or race. So why not White accordingly. That’s a POB issue at best.

Comment: Related: [“White” vs. “a white” vs. “a white person”](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/88140/white-vs-a-white-vs-a-white-person)

Comment: Possibly because Caucasian (not sure if anyone except Americans use that) originally referred to the Caucasus mountain? Just because one or two sources capitalize black and white, I would be careful with that. It sounds a little like "whataboutism"...BTW, as Anthony Burgess once pointed out, there are people in parts of Asia that are just as "black" or even blacker than people from Africa. That muddies the waters...

Comment: There's a lot more that needs to be said about this than comes in a comment to a closed question, but 1) Orthography is a convention. 2) Not everything must be consistent in a convention. 3) There is a reason for (currently) deciding for the convention to change to Black and white. none of these are obvious, but I think (in the US) 'Black' is not a literal, it refers to those of African descent from the slave trade, and is capitalized because people realized it is comparable to Asians, Mormons, British. And 'white' is not capitalized for the same reason, it's not an ethnicity (within the US).

Comment: @Mitch off-topic.... I used to know some people that live in the US who are of Haitian descent, who took  exception to the term African-American.  And I had a Jamaican  ex-roommate once who claimed he was "African by way of Jamaica" to my new roommate who was actually from South Africa. When asked "Do you speak Shangan, or Zulu, or Xhosa?" He replied, and I quote, "Hunnh?" ... "Then you aren't fckn African! You're just another black fella."

Comment: @Mitch: You can still post an answer [if you want](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/316139/711871). 'When a question is closed, the server still accepts answers for 4 hours'.

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul You have to have already started the answer -before- the item is closed. -and- then you have 4 hours to submit. Once a question is closed you can't start a new answer because it doesn't have a 'answer' button in the UI.

Comment: @Cascabel Right. I could be called Irish-American even though I don't speak Irish or have relatives after 3 generations from there. Words aren't literal, they mean all sorts of different things that are not the first entry in the dictionary.

Comment: @Mitch: Did you read the linked answer though? You can still post an answer.. lemme show you: see below:

Comment: @DecapitatedSoul Oh, I see now. I didn't understand what it was saying because it was not referring to how to 'get back' the submit button as the system intended. Rather the 'solution' is a backdoor programming hack, which is not intended by the system designers., ie it is cheating. Yes, it is literally 'possible', but not at all intended and could easily be fixed to prevent it in the future. Clever solution but not expected by the system.

Comment: "Black is not literal, it refers to those of African descent from the slave trade...". That is a very US-centric notion. What would you call a person that is born, raised and living in Africa? Would they not be black? I agree that "black" in the context of classifying people is not always used literally. However, I think it is wrong to use "black" as anything else than either a signifyer of skin color, or as the name of a race. If the latter, than it can be capitalized, but it is no more eligible for capitalization than "white" when used as the name of the race. @Mitch

Comment: Also relevant: [Is "Black" correct, incorrect, or could it be used as either "Black" or "black"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/553249/is-black-correct-incorrect-or-could-it-be-used-as-either-black-or-black)

Comment: @A.Kvåle Yes, it is very US centric. I did not qualify that I was speaking for AmE. Also, the ''w'hite/'B'lack thing is very recent (at least to me) from even the past year (which means it is probably started gaining currency 5 to 10 years ago. Whether you think it is wrong or logical or not, what I've described is a -convention- and style guides in the US are starting to use it. Since the OP assumes 'Black' is capitalized but not 'white', I take the answer to be at least in the US.

Comment: Because 1) it's covert racism and 2) it implied that white people have no culture.

Comment: The OP has edited this question and there are 2 votes to reopen, but I'm voting to keep it closed. It already has an excellent answer, and the linked duplicate now has a new answer that brings it up-to-date. Any further answers on this topic should be posted on the duplicate rather than here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

One explanation for the discrepancy is offered by Nell Irvin Painter in their opinion piece for the *[Washington Post](https://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:niQqPBfZ_agJ:https://www.washingtonpost.com/opinions/2020/07/22/why-white-should-be-capitalized/%20&cd=3&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=it)*

> These two identities don’t simply mirror each other — one works through a pronounced group identity [Black]; the other more often is lived as unraced individuality [white]. However much you might see yourself as an individual, if you’re black, you also have to contend with other people’s views. W.E.B. Du Bois summed this up as “twoness,” as seeing yourself as yourself but also knowing that other people see you as a black person. You don’t have to be a black nationalist to see yourself as black.
>
> In contrast, until quite recently white Americans rarely saw themselves as raced — as white. Most of them, anyway. The people who have embraced “white” as a racial identity have been white nationalists, Ku Klux Klansmen and their ilk.

In July 20 2020 the following statement was released [emphasis in bold mine.]

> NEW YORK (AP) — After changing its usage rules last month to capitalize the word “Black” when used in the context of race and culture, [The Associated Press on Monday said it would not do the same for “white.”](https://apnews.com/article/7e36c00c5af0436abc09e051261fff1f)
>
> The AP said **white people in general have much less shared history and culture, and don’t have the experience of being discriminated against because of skin color.**
> […]
> CBS News said it would capitalize white, although not when referring to white supremacists, white nationalists or white privilege.
>
> Some proponents believe that keeping white lowercase is actually anti-Black, saying it perpetuates the idea that whites are the default race.

Comment: Thanks for giving me the heads up about the 4 hour grace period...

Comment: Could the naysayers please come back and delete their DVs? I am not asking for an upvote, just a revision.

Comment: @Mari-LouA I am assuming that your ultimate purpose is to reopen the Q? I have already VTROed.

Comment: @Cascabel No, my aim was to validate the Community-wiki post. This answer is basically a duplicate, albeit more nuanced and detailed, of another in the older question. Feel free to reopen. I won't protest.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Sometimes I think that we should be comparing older and newer posts to decide on which we would prefer as the best...dictionaries do regular revisions according to new knowledge and language. We should too.

Comment: @Cascabel We can update older posts too. There's even an SE badge called the Necromancer which encourages this behaviour. Still, I wasn't expecting the OP to agree with my judgement call, I mean not as quickly as they did.

Comment: @Mari-LouA Unfortunately, it is called Necromancer because we have to go digging in the _cementario_ for very old questions. Usually it does not come to our attention until we receive a post like this. As for me, I often have  **what I think** are interesting questions (usually while washing my hair) but upon doing _the required research_, I realize that someone has already done it in a dupe. Sometimes the Q&A is good, but many of the first posts from the beginning of SE would be closed these days for any variety of reasons...

Comment: ... I think there should be some kind of balance between automatically VTCing for  a crappy dupe in exchange for a higher quality, but newer Q&A.

Comment: @Cascabel: A very similar question arose less than five months ago: [Is "Black" correct, incorrect, or could it be used as either "Black" or "black"?](https://english.stackexchange.com/questions/553249/is-black-correct-incorrect-or-could-it-be-used-as-either-black-or-black) I posted an answer to that question because the Associated Press's style guideline on the question had recently changed and the older question didn't include any answers addressing that change.

Comment: @SvenYargs Right...However, I sometimes think that our system of closure for dupe is not actually enhancing the usability of the site. Many new users might stumble upon our site by happenstance, and arrive at the newer question for whatever, google analytics? Then they see it is closed and they say bye bye and we lose a potential new user......I gotta think on that overnight...

Comment: There are too many dupes for some questions, and many of them have very good answers.  
That said, I think there needs to be a higher level of moderation that could curate the collection and produce fewer sloppy posts. Right now, it does not look professional.\

Comment: @Cascabel: One option that is available to moderators is to merge questions (and answers), which might be helpful in a situation like this one, where the official "open" posted question has only older and arguably somewhat out-of-date answers. But my impression is that EL&U moderators aren't big on merging questions: according to [2020: a year in moderation](https://english.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/14899/2020-a-year-in-moderation), the mods at this site performed a total of just eight question mergers in 2020.